# Schedule recurring message with random data in MassTransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, quartz-scheduler, masstransit

I want to schedule recurring message in MassTransit, but each time the message is sent to the queue I want to generate same random data.

for now I have such code

```
        var scheduleEndPoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"{BusConstants.RabbitMqUri}/quartz"));
        await scheduleEndPoint.ScheduleRecurringSend(
            new Uri($"{BusConstants.RabbitMqUri}/{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArticlesImportServiceQueue"]}"),
            new ArticlesImportRecurringSchedule(),
            ArticlesImportNotificationMapper.MapFromFile());
```

The problem is that `ArticlesImportNotificationMapper.MapFromFile()` is called only first time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scheduled message is just that, scheduled -- it isn't modified in any way at the time of delivery.

If you need to generate random data, or modify the contents of the message, I would suggest that you schedule a separate recurring message, such as `GenerateAndSendCommand`, and create a consumer that receives that messages and then sends the actual `CommandWithRandomData` to the configured consumer after generating it and plugging the random data, etc.